# Notepad++ UDL: Dot as operator and decimal separator at the same time

Tags: operators, notepad++, decimal-point

I want to create a UDL that uses dot as decimal separator aswell as an operator.

In the UDL configuration i put `.` in the "Operators 1" section and i set "Decimal Separator" to "Dot", but it's not working correctly.

[image: Example image]

Now, is there a way to make the `.` adapt to numbers keeping it as an operator?

Comment: I specify my NPP version to be 7.89

Comment: What is not working? What do you mean with “not displaying correctly”?

Comment: I mean that the dot in the expression `diam * 3.14` must be the same color as the digits that make up the number `3.14`